# Two dim array, pointer to part of it and stack corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why next code gives me **stack around variable x was corrupted**?

```
char x[1][21];
char *ch = x[1];
strcpy(ch,"12345678901234567890");

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    cout << i << ": " << &x[1][i] << " " << x[1][i] << endl;
```

output:

```
0: 12345678901234567890 1
1: 2345678901234567890 2
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *ch = x[1]; //error - index out of range
```

It is wrong. You should write:

```
char *ch = x[0]; //ok  - index within range
```

as `x` is declared as `char x[1][21]` which means `0` is the only *valid* index for first dimension. `1` falls out of range.

Answer (score 6):

`char x[1][21];` is a 1 x 21 matrix.

The line `char *ch = x[1];` is accessing the second row. So that's already out of bounds.

Try changing it to:

```
char x[2][21];
char *ch = x[1];
strcpy(ch,"12345678901234567890");

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    cout << i << ": " << &x[1][i] << " " << x[1][i] << endl;
```

or

```
char x[1][21];
char *ch = x[0];
strcpy(ch,"12345678901234567890");

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    cout << i << ": " << &x[0][i] << " " << x[0][i] << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a one-element array and then accessing it's second element (index 1, the first element is index 0).